# Xbmc won't install due to dependency issues on Lubuntu quantal

Tags: software-installation, 12.10, xbmc

I have a mac mini g4 with Ubuntu 12.0 with kernel version 3.5.0-17-powerpc-smp (ppc).

Now I want to get XBMC but I can't get it installed...

Examples:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xbmc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xbmc : Depends: xbmc-bin (>= 3:12.2-1~ppa1~quantal) but it is not installable
        Depends: xbmc-bin (< 3:12.2-1~ppa1~quantal.1~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

With the software center I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

xbmc: Depends: xbmc-bin (>= 3:12.2-1~ppa1~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: xbmc-bin (< 3:12.2-1~ppa1~quantal.1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

Also tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties pkg-config
```

I have tried the PPAs renniewaldoc and wsnipex without success.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties pkg-config
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xbmc
```

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Installing_XBMC_for_Linux

Comment: Still the same problem: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xbmc : Depends: xbmc-bin (>= 3:12.9.5-git201306162050~051253d-1~ppa1~quantal) but it is not installable
        Depends: xbmc-bin (< 3:12.9.5-git201306162050~051253d-1~ppa1~quantal.1~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this installed using the following command:

```
sudo aptitude install xbmc
```

Aptitude tries harder to resolve certain problems. It will present you with some options along the way, to which you will have to make the right choices.